# How to pass parameters to Rails "delegate"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

   delegate :publish_group_creation, :to => 'MyAppModules::Publisher'  
   after_create :publish_group_creation

end
```

The thing is that `Publisher.publish_group_creation` receives 1 argument (the group that's gonna be published)

I tried something like this;

`delegate :publish_group_creation, :to => 'MyAppModules::Publisher', :group => self`

but it doesn't work, what is right way to pass parameters using `delegate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods called via callbacks don't receive parameters in Rails.

Try this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :publish_group

  private
  def publish_group
    MyAppModules::Publisher.publish_group_creation(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: If the Publisher module's methods will all apply to your Group model, then you'll want to go with Mike's answer. I was assuming that Group and Publisher were mostly unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, that's how currently is my code, that would be nice if we could pass 'em inline!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for your scenario, but you might try reworking this a bit. Something like

```
module MyAppModules::Publisher
  def publish_group_creation
    ...
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base

  include MyAppModules::Publisher

  after_create :publish_group_creation

end
```